# Add Notification Badge for particular grid in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

1. How to add notification badge for particular index.
2. I was created a Grid suing Gridview.builder now I want to add notification badge on 3 rd `index(All List Count)`  of grid list I don't know how to add in particular list

This is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class StudentView extends StatefulWidget {
  const StudentView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StudentView> createState() => _StudentViewState();
}

class _StudentViewState extends State<StudentView> {


  var notificationDetailsList = [];

  List category = [
    'Fruits',
    'Grocery',
    'Vegetable',
    'All List Count',
    'Notification',
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    // print(notlength);
    return Container(
      child: Center(
          child: GridView.builder(
              itemCount: catergory.length,
              gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                  crossAxisCount: 2, childAspectRatio: 5 / 2),
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Card(
                    color: Colors.blue.shade100,
                    child: Center(child: Text(catergory[index])));
              })),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You have to customize your Card widget, then assign the notification badge to that widget.

Comment: any example you have article link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this method and replace my condition with your condition.

```
import 'package:badges/badges.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class StudentView extends StatefulWidget {
  const StudentView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StudentView> createState() => _StudentViewState();
}

    class _StudentViewState extends State<StudentView> {
      var notificationDetailsList = [];
      List category = [
        'Fruits',
        'Grocery',
        'Vegetable',
        'All List Count',
        'Notification',
      ];
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        // print(notlength);
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(),
          body: Center(
            child: GridView.builder(
              itemCount: category.length,
              gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                  crossAxisCount: 2, childAspectRatio: 5 / 2),
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Stack(
                  clipBehavior: Clip.none,
                  children: [
                    Card(
                      color: Colors.blue.shade100,
                      child: Center(
                        child: Text(
                          category[index],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    index.isEven
                        ? Positioned(
                            right: 0,
                            top: -6,
                            child: Badge(
                              badgeContent: const Text('3'),
                            ),
                          )
                        : const SizedBox.shrink(),
                  ],
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: It's all my Pleasure